# PhantomJS returns Access Denied with Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs

I have been using PhantomJS with Python selenium to scrap a website for a while and now I am getting this page instead.

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>

You don't have permission to access "http://elpais.com/" on this server <p>
Reference #18.4adedd58.1510878066.6ade65ca


</p></body></html>
```

This is how I start `PhantomJS`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

def open_headless_browser():
    dcap = dict(DesiredCapabilities.PHANTOMJS)
    dcap["phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent"] = (
        "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/53 "
        "(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/15.0.87"
    )
    driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(desired_capabilities=dcap)
    driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
    driver.implicitly_wait(1)
return driver
```

Comment: is this your full source?

Comment: As the driver always fails to find the elements I am looking for, I ran `print(driver.page_source)` and this is what I got?!

Comment: What I mean is, you have to share your full code, with imports...

Comment: I added the imports in the original post

Comment: No one is going to help you if you keep hiding your full source, where is the call to the website? what are your configs?

Comment: @user1767754 - Why would I need to hide anything?! This is the call to open the url: `driver = open_headless_browser()` and then `driver.get("http://elpais.com/")` - Then whatever element I try to find is not three. So running `driver.page_source` prints Access Denied. Please clarify what you mean by 'configs'

Comment: For me it works fine...did you try it to often, that you got locked?

Comment: In fact, I did... For a lot of time that I can't even remember when I started :) - Do you think there is any solution to this or I should just let go?

Comment: Probably there is a cool down period, for a couple of days, if you have dynamic IP, I would restart it. Worst case use Selenium with Proxy, and keep in my for future, to not access the page in high intervals. Just let your request sleep for a fraction of time.